# How to test if value stored in double fit in long? (rounding yes, but truncating no)

Tags: java, casting, double, long-integer, truncate

I think that question is pretty straight. but here is an examples.

Example below is OK. I can take rounding and no truncating was done here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 9.9;
    long l = (long)d;
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Output:

```
9
```

And now number out of range of long:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 99999999999999999999999999999999.9;
    long l = (long)d;
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

Output:

```
9223372036854775807
```

This one troubles me. I cannot continue work with completely different number. I would rather get an error or an exception.

Is there any way to detect this in Java?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can compare it with `Long.MIN_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE`:

```
public static boolean fitsLong(double d) {
    return d >= Long.MIN_VALUE && d < Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Somewhat more sofisticated approach is to use `BigDecimal`:

```
double value = 1234567.9;
long l = BigDecimal.valueOf(value)
                   .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
                   .longValueExact(); // 1234568

double value = 99999999999999999999999999999999.9;
long l = BigDecimal.valueOf(value)
                   .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
                   .longValueExact(); // ArithmeticException
```

This way you can control how the rounding is performed.

You may ask, why there's strict inequality in `fitsLong`: `d < Long.MAX_VALUE`. Actually that's because the `Long.MAX_VALUE` itself cannot be represented as double number. When you cast `(double)Long.MAX_VALUE`, there's not enough precision in `double` type to represent it, so the closest representable value is selected which is `9223372036854775808.0` (`Long_MAX_VALUE+1.0`). So were it `d <= Long.MAX_VALUE` it would return `true` for number which is actually a little bigger as in this comparison `Long.MAX_VALUE` constant is promoted to double type. On the other hand `Long.MIN_VALUE` can be exactly represented in `double` type, thus here we have `>=`.

Also it's interesting why the following works:

```
double value = -9223372036854775809.9; // Long.MIN_VALUE-1.9
System.out.println(fitsLong(value)); // returns true
```

That's because you actually did not subtract anything from the `Long.MIN_VALUE`. See:

```
double d1 = Long.MIN_VALUE;
double d2 = -9223372036854775809.9;
System.out.println(d1 == d2); // true
```

The double precision is not enough to distinguish between `-9223372036854775808` and `-9223372036854775809.9`, so it's actually the same double number. During the compilation it's converted to binary form, and binary form for these two numbers is the same. Thus having compiled program you cannot distinguish whether `-9223372036854775808` or `-9223372036854775809.9` was in the source code.

If you feel that it's still the issue, construct the `BigDecimal` from the `String`:

```
long l = new BigDecimal("-9223372036854775808.2")
                   .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
                   .longValueExact(); // ok, -9223372036854775808

long l = new BigDecimal("-9223372036854775808.9")
                   .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
                   .longValueExact(); // ArithmeticException
```

Comment: For the first solution) Actually you cannot. I tried it and it wont work. For example try a value 9223372036854775809.9 which is incremented Long.MAX_VALUE by 2.9. It will pass.

Comment: You are right, but when I use 9223372036854775807.0 for both solutions. FitsLong gives me true and BigDecimal throws an exception. That double value may be unchanged, but at least one of the solutions has to be wrong.

Comment: @arenaq double has 53 bits of mantissa and can be precise only to ~15-17 digits. There's no way for it to differentiate between 9223372036854775809.9 and 9223372036854775807 http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714

Comment: @arenaq, that's a subtle question. As `Long.MAX_VALUE` cannot be exactly expressed in double and its canonical representation is a little bit bigger, thus probably you should exclude it from `fitsLong` (change `<=` to strict `<`). But on the other hand, you may consider this case as rounding, not the truncation (e.g. `System.out.println((long)1000000000000000010.0);` yields `1000000000000000000`, but this is rounding).

Comment: I know, but that does not explain why these solutions behave differently for the same double. Try this code http://pastebin.com/FT7dtd5p

Comment: @arenaq, because in comparison both numbers are promoted to `double` type, thus `Long.MAX_VALUE` becomes the same double number which is actually a little bigger, thus the comparison produces true. On the other hand, `BigDecimal.valueOf` works with exact canonical representation of the number and knows that it's bigger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @TagirValeev so that fitsLong solutions is wrong and BigDecimal is right? I am little confused...

Comment: @arenaq, I edited the answer and explained this corner case, also replacing the rounding example with negative numbers as it's sounds more logical now.

Answer (score 1):

When you cast a floating point type to an `int` or `long`, the result is either the nearest integer (rounding towards zero), or the `MIN_VALUE` or `MAX_VALUE` for `int` or `long`.  See [JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3).

Hence, one alternative would be to do the typecast and then test for the appropriate `MIN_VALUE` or `MAX_VALUE`.

Note that `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `9223372036854775807` ... which is the number your test program outputs!

(However, this doesn't work if you are casting a floating point type to `byte`, `char` or `short`.  See the link above for the explanation.)